# Automatically checking the existence of folders in a path

Tags: windows, path, directory

I have a lot of folders, each folder has someone's surname as the name. I want to move all these surname folders into a different path, how would I automatically check the path I want to move them to, for the same name.

For example. Let's say in `C:/Downloads` I have a folder called `Nunes`. How would I make it so when I upload another folder called `nunes`, it alerts me that that folder already exists?

Comment: remove javascript tag please

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I got mixed up. Removed.